# I have curl support, but curl_init fails

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl

Error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

Of course, my first though is that something happened server side that killed curl. So I ssh in, and all's well with php5-curl. I load up phpinfo() and see curl module's author listed. This is the only curl mention in phpinfo, though.

Am I missing something here?

The back story: this is a Joomla site ive been working on for a Realtor. Its sitting on a corporate ubuntu server that hosts several other live sites. The particular view that throws the error now has always worked fine. The project was tabled for several weeks while the client worked out some red tape for her mls/idx feed, but when that was cleaned up I went in to finish config and see this error.

Odd, right?

Comment: Close duplicate, but curl IS mentioned briefly in my phpinfo.

Comment: do you see something like [this](https://imgur.com/juai3X3) when you run `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Only because it is mentioned somewhere in your phpinfo does not mean, it is actually installed. There are a few other posts here on SO with slightly different answers - did you check them out?

Comment: Fantastic! I KNEW I was supposed to see the config block. Much appreciated. It's installed via apt-get. Isn't that supposed to enable support automatically? Regardless, will look into enabling.